# Rails 4, Postgresql - Custom query incorrectly constructed inside controller, correctly in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, wildcard

I'm trying to write a query that will match last names that at least start with the submitted characters. No matter how I construct the query though, whether I use ILIKE, LIKE, ~*, or @@, the query that's constructed when the method is called from the controller changes the query to a simple = operator.

The full method:

```
def self.search(params)
  if params.empty?
    return Evaluation.none
  end

  results = nil

  if params.include?(:appointment_start_date) && params.include?(:appointment_end_date)
    results = Evaluation.where(appointment_time: params.delete(:appointment_start_date)..params.delete(:appointment_end_date))
  end

  params.each do |key, value|
    case key
    when :l_name
      results = (results || Evaluation).where("to_tsquery('english', '#{value}:*') @@ to_tsvector('english', l_name)")
    when :ssn
      results = (results || Evaluation).joins(:candidate).where(candidates: { ssn: value })
    else
      results = (results || Evaluation).where("#{key} = ?", value)
    end
  end

  results.includes(:evaluation_type, :agency, :psychologist)
end
```

But the pertinent piece is:

```
.where("to_tsquery('english', '#{value}:*') @@ to_tsvector('english', l_name)")
```

If I call the method from the Rails console, the expected SQL query is generated and the correct records are returned. Now here's the controller action:

```
def search
  authorize! :read, Evaluation
  @evaluations = Evaluation.search(evaluation_search_params).paginate(page: params[:page]).decorate
end
```

Let's say the user submits 'kel' for the search. For some flippin' reason, the generated query is

```
SELECT "evaluations".* FROM "evaluations" WHERE (l_name = 'kel') ORDER BY "evaluations"."appointment_time" ASC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

(There's a default_scope on Evaluation, hence the ORDER BY, so that's not part of the mystery.)

I've tried removing the pagination and the Draper decoration to no avail, and both of those also work fine in the console. So, my question is, why the heck is the generated query different when called from the controller? I'm seriously at my wit's end with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you param keys strings instead of symbols? That might be affecting which branch of the case statement is selected. Try debugging and stepping through the code if you are unsure.

You may just need to change to string values:

```
params.each do |key, value|
  case key
  when "l_name"
    results = (results || Evaluation).where("to_tsquery('english', '#{value}:*') @@ to_tsvector('english', l_name)")
  when "ssn"
    results = (results || Evaluation).joins(:candidate).where(candidates: { ssn: value })
  else
    results = (results || Evaluation).where("#{key} = ?", value)
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! I can't believe I forgot that params keys are strings when submitted to the controller.